# Stored procedures return table function, having hard time finish it, stuck at the last few parts

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, table-functions

I want to create a stored procedure `Report_NEWTotal_Salary_ByDept` using (by
calling) the table function I created here:

```
select 
    e.Dept_No, d.Dept_Name, Count(e.Dept_No),
    SUM(e.salary) as Sum_Salary,
    AVG(e.salary)  as AVE_Salary
from 
    EMPLOYEE e
join 
    DEPARTMENT d ON e.dno = d.dnumber
group by 
    e.Dept_No, d.Dept_Name
```

Basically I want to return a new table `Report_NEWTotal_Salary_ByDept`. I want  this table to have 7 new columns:

```
Dept_No (Int)
Dept_Name (Char(30))
COUNT_Emp (INT)
SUM_Salary (INT)
AVE_Salary (INT)
New_SUM_Salary (INT)
New_AVE_Salary (INT)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Create procedure Report_Newtotal_Salary_ByDept
    @Dept_No
    @Dept_Name(30)
As
    set Count_Emp

    Select 
        Sum_Salary, Ave_Salary, new_Ave_Salary
    where 
        new ave_salary = ave_salary???
```

Please consider giving me advice on how to finish it.

Comment: what is new_Ave_Salary based on?

Comment: @Dbug Hey thanks for help, it is based on my database, is there a way I could contact you? the code aren't that long, but I can only post one question

Comment: Can you update the post?  Of put it in a SQL Fiddle and post that link here?

Comment: @dbug my email is gethbonow at gmail